# Are Suspend and Pause synonyms?

Tags: terminology, software

I have a question.
Is **suspend and pause** the same action?
For example, user can choose one of these actions:

- Start debugging
- Suspend debugging
- Stop debugging

Would you think I could swap suspend for pause?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We shouldn't assume that these terms are interchangeable because often 'Suspend' has a more specific meaning than the term 'Pause' in common usage. However, if there is only one type of state in your application then they will obviously mean the same thing to the user regardless of which term you use.

From common usage suspend or suspension is usually associated with a predetermined amount of time (e.g. two month suspension for an action on the field) whereas pause is a more generic term that is determined by a user depending on the context (e.g. press pause on the play button).

I think it is only in situations where there might be more than one state in which you temporarily stop what the application is doing that you will have to be more specific otherwise the users will be confused.